# how to insert function in my php page instead than anchor tag

Tags: php

How can I Insert a function in my php page instead of an anchor tag?

My problem is in this line:

```
echo 'Click <a href="add-calendar.php?fname='.$fname.'&lname='.$lname.'&sdate='.$startdate.'&edate='.$enddate.'&description='.$description.'&title='.$title.'">HERE</a> to add it on the calendar';
```

Here is my code

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking_members WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

{


$id = $_GET["id"];
$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE booking_members SET status='Paid',payment_status ='Paid' WHERE id = '$id'");

    $fname = $row['firstname'];
    $lname = $row['lastname'];
    $startdate = $row['start_date'];
    $enddate = $row['end_date'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $title = $row['title'];

echo 'The Request has been approved. You may now go <a href="admin-panel.php?$id">Back to the previous page</a><br>';
echo 'Click <a href="add-calendar.php?fname='.$fname.'&lname='.$lname.'&sdate='.$startdate.'&edate='.$enddate.'&description='.$description.'&title='.$title.'">HERE</a> to add it on the calendar';
```

Comment: `function doit(){ // execute code }` `if(isset($_REQUEST['button'])){ doit(); }` basically.

Comment: What kind of code are you expecting?

Comment: what do you mean, a "function"? That's HTML you're generating, which gets sent to the remote browser. You cannot execute PHP on the client-side.

Comment: *"How can I Insert a funtion in my php page instead of an anchor tag?"* --- Let's get the terminology correct. This is an anchor tag => `<a name="test"></a>` that works in conjunction with `<a href="#test">LINK</a>`

Comment: You might want to create a hidden form with those values in it and use a submit button instead of a link.  Using variables like that in a URL may be harmful, especially if they are generated from a database query.